# Is there a way to send_file() folium map without saving it locally?

Tags: flask, folium

Is there a way to `send_file()` folium map without saving it locally?

I do not want to store it on server as HTML file, just want to give it away at once, but I do not know how.

```
# current state of business
my_map.save(file_name)
# TODO: delete file
return send_file(file_name, as_attachment=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`my_map.get_root().render()` will send HTML as a string

In that way browser will propose to download it instead of showing:

```
from flask import Response


return Response(
        my_map.get_root().render(),
        mimetype='text/html',
        headers={'Content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=map.html'})
```